# How to change login and logout links dynamically in HTML page in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have the following HTML code. I have 2 php files: login.php and logout.php. When any user first comes to my page, I would like him to see the login link. After clicking log in (which I will process with my login.php file) I want to change that login link to logout (and on click of that logout.php file will be processed)

In the following code, how could I dynamically change login and logout links? Currently I have given 2 different links for login and logout which is not a good idea.

```
<header class="group">
    <nav class="group">         
        <ul>
          <li><a href="register.php" title="">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php" title="">Login</a></li>   
              <li><a href="logout.php" title="">Logout</a></li>             
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: put logut button in the user's homepage,and this is wat we normally do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a session to check whether user logged in or not. If not, create a session variable and set once logged in. Clear the session variable on log out. So you can check

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
//your logout link
}else{
//your login link
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

You need to set a variable `$logged_user` to identify whether the user is logged in or not

```
<header class="group">
<nav class="group">         
    <ul>
        <?php if ($logged_user) { ?>
            <li><a href="logout.php" title="">Logout</a></li>             
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li><a href="register.php" title="">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php" title="">Login</a></li>   

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
        if ($signout) 
        { 
            echo "<li><a href=logout.php >Logout</a></li>";
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "<li><a href=register.php >Register</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href=login.php >Login</a></li>";
        } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
        echo "<form method='POST' action='".userLogout()."'>";  ?>
            <li><button type="submit" name="userlogout" id="logout-button" class="button-logout">LOGOUT</button></li>

<?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="login">LOGIN</a></li>
    </form>
<?php }
?>
```