# How to change login and logout links dynamically in Java jsp?

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets, session-cookies

I have this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721614/how-to-change-login-and-logout-links-dynamically-in-html-page-in-php) in this forum while learning jsp to build a login/logout on the `top menu bar`. I wonder is it the same way to use session and should this session object be in `LoginServle`t or `SessionServlet` to control this UI behaviour, and how can I achieve this result if I use MongoDB with the session?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where your login/logout will lead to. In the grand scheme, it really doesn't matter. For example, if you chose to direct it towards LoginServlet, you would handle it like so:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if(session.getAttribute("ATTRIBUTE")==null){//Make sure that when the user logs in, you set the attribute
    //They are not logged in
    response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
}else{
    //They are logged in
    response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
}
```

If you want to display whether the user is logged in or logged out, you can use the `<c:choose>` tag like so:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.username != null}">
        You are logged in!
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        You are not logged in :(
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Don't forget to important the taglib above the `<head>`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: I want to show the login/logout status on the top navbar instead of different page.

Comment: @Stu_Dent I've updated the answer. Does it answer your question?